# How to resolve java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException in Scala 2.8.0?

Tags: exception, scala

I'm using Scala 2.8.0 and trying to read pipe delimited file like in code snipped below:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) :Unit = {
    if (args.length > 0) {
      val lines = scala.io.Source.fromPath("QUICK!LRU-2009-11-15.psv")
     for (line <-lines)
       print(line)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:261)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:319)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:157)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:29)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:29)
        at scala.io.Codec.wrap(Codec.scala:65)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:29)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:29)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.next(Iterator.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:745)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.head(Iterator.scala:732)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$24.hasNext(Iterator.scala:405)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$20.hasNext(Iterator.scala:320)
        at scala.io.Source.hasNext(Source.scala:209)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:534)
        at scala.io.Source.foreach(Source.scala:143)
...
at infillreports.Main$.main(Main.scala:8)
        at infillreports.Main.main(Main.scala)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) :Unit = {
    if (args.length > 0) {
      val lines = scala.io.Source.fromPath("QUICK!LRU-2009-11-15.psv")("UTF-8")
      for (line <-lines)
        print(line)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope you'll take the time to understand why adding "UTF-8" here was necessary, and how it changed the behavior of the reading of characters from the input stream. If you don't get it, please elaborate your question here or ask a new question concerning bytes, characters, and character encodings.

Comment: In scala 2.12.3 you shoud write
    Source.fromFile(fileName)(Codec("utf-8"))

Comment: import scala.io.{Source, Codec}

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with this same issue and this answer helped me. I wanted to extend on the comment of seh regarding the 'why this works'. The answer should lie on the method signature:

```
def fromFile(file: JFile)(implicit codec: Codec): BufferedSource
```

It takes an implict codec parameter. Yet, on the example, a string is provided, not a codec. A second translation is taking place behind the scenes:
The companion object of the class Codec defines an apply method from String:

```
def apply(encoding: String): Codec
```

so the compiler has done some work for us:
val lines = Source.fromFile(someFile)(Codec("UTF-8"))

Given that Codec is implicit, if you are calling this method several times, you can also create a Codec object in the scope of your call:

```
implicit val codec = Codec("UTF-8")
val lines = Source.fromFile(someFile)
val moreLines = Source.fromFile(someOtherFile)
```

I hope I got that right (I'm still a Scala n00b,  getting my grips on it - feel free to correct where needed)

Comment: Actually, since `Codec.apply` is not an implicit conversion, there is no reason for the compiler to silently call it. In fact its is `Codec.string2codec` which is called here (as it **is** an implicit conversion from `String` to `Codec`)

Answer (score 5):

To add to Daniel C. Sobral's answer, you can also try something like this:

```
val products = Source.fromFile("products.txt")("UTF-8").getLines().toList;

for(p <- products){
        println("product :" + p);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a more generic solution:

```
implicit val codec = Codec("UTF-8")
codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
```

with the two settings, you can avoid the malformed data in file.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to try your solution because the accepted answer did not solve my problem. But it doesn't compile, as the compiler does not recognize the value CodingErrorAction.REPLACE. I have imported scala.io._, which namespace am I missing?

Comment: You are missing `java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction`