# Parsing separated text file in Scala

Tags: scala, parsing

When i trying parse txt file at 200k line in file i have this error:

> java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1

After i got error  my program break:

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile( path)
for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines.drop(1)) {
    line.split('|').toList.drop(1)
    }
```

If I understand correctly, the error is `in io.Source.fromFile( path)`.
How i can skip bad rows ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException in Scala 2.8.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757272/how-to-resolve-java-nio-charset-unmappablecharacterexception-in-scala-2-8-0)

Comment: i have this error not at first row. I have error at 200k row

Comment: It still seems to be a character encoding issue. Either you need to handle non-ascii characters or make sure that your file only has acii values.

Comment: My solution is :`import scala.io.Codec
implicit val codec = Codec("cp1251")
codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to deal with encodings issues yourself.
One of these 2 encodings often work for me:

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile( path, enc = Codec.UTF8.name)
for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines.drop(1)) {
    line.split('|').toList.drop(1)
    }
```

or

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile( path, enc = Codec.ISO8859.name)
```